# How do you fix this code so that if the user inputs an uppercase or lowercase letter, as long as its the right letter, they'll be told its index:

Tags: java, string, char

In this code, the user gets 3 guesses of letters in the name and then the user can guess the actual name. Does anybody know how to fix this code so that if the user enters "m" they'll still be told where its position is even though the name starts with a capital M?

```
//import java scanner
import java.util.Scanner;

//declare variables
class Main 
{
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  String name = "Matt";
  String guessedName;
  int nameLength, position, guesses;
  char guess;
  
  //method for guessLetter
  public void guessLetter()
  { 
    nameLength = name.length();
    System.out.println("The name I am thinking of is " + nameLength + " letters long.\nYou will be able to pick three letters and I'll let you know the location  letter occurs in the name. Then you can guess the name.");
    guesses = 3;
    while(guesses >= 1)
    {
      System.out.println("Guess one letter?");
      guess = scan.nextLine().charAt(0);
      letters();
      guesses -= 1;
    }
  
  }

  //method for guess Name
  public void guessedName()
  {
    System.out.println("Guess what you think the name is?");
    guessedName = scan.nextLine();
    if(guessedName.equalsIgnoreCase(name)){
      System.out.println("Correct, that is the name!");
    }
    else{
      System.out.println("Wrong, that is not the correct name.");
      System.out.println("The name is " + name + ".");
    }
  }

  //method for letters
  public void letters()
  {
    if(name.indexOf(guess)>-1)
    {
      position = name.indexOf(guess);
      System.out.println(guess + " is at position " + position + ".");
    }
    else
    {
      System.out.println(guess + " is not in the name!");
    }
  }

  
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    Main prog = new Main ();
    prog.guessLetter();
    prog.guessedName();
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not simply convert the `name` to all [lowercase](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase())?

Comment: I would like it to do it without having to convert the name or ask the user to type it in lower/uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

Just check for the character in a loop.  That's what `indexOf` does.  Something like this.

```
public void letters() {
    String[] chars = name.split("");
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
       if(chars[i].equalsIgnoreCase(guess)) {
           System.out.println(guess + " is at position " + i + ".");
           return;
       }
    }
    System.out.println(guess + " is not in the name!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a comparison that ignores case, but you don't want to convert the `name`, then you need to test twice - once for each case.

```java
if (name.indexOf(guess) > -1) {
    position = name.indexOf(guess);
    System.out.println(guess + " is at position " + position + ".");
}
else {
    if (Character.isUpperCase(guess)) {
        guess = Character.toLowerCase(guess);
    }
    else {
        guess = Character.toUpperCase(guess);
    }
    if (name.indexOf(guess) > -1) {
        position = name.indexOf(guess);
        System.out.println(guess + " is at position " + position + ".");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(guess + " is not in the name!");
    }
}
```

Basically the above code does the following:

- If `guess` matches a letter in `name` then we are done.
- If not, then check the case of `guess`.

  - If `guess` is upper case, convert it to lower case.
  - If `guess` is lower case, convert it to upper case.
  - Recheck to see whether the converted `guess` matches a letter in `name`.

Refer to class [java.lang.Character](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html)

Alternatively, you can use [regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(String.valueOf(guess), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(name);
if (matcher.find()) {
    position = matcher.start();
    System.out.println(guess + " is at position " + position + ".");
}
else {
    System.out.println(guess + " is not in the name!");
}
```